# Why do grammars in Chomsky Normal Form have derivations of length 2n-1?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, normal-forms

I would like to know how they obtained the expression $2n-1$ as said from the excerpt of [article](http://people.cs.clemson.edu/~goddard/texts/theoryOfComputation/9a.pdf) (p.3):

> The key advantage is that in Chomsky Normal Form, every derivation of a string of n letters has exactly 2n−1 steps.

I could get how $2n$ comes since there are only 2 variables on the R.H.S of each production but couldn't get how the expression $−1$ came in $2n−1$.

Comment: When I read about this, I proved it by induction.

Comment: @justin This is a typical question that can be interesting but was formulated in a poor way (hence the downvotes). As Yuval Filmus expressed, you should edit your answer so that it reflects your question more properly (e.g. This article says this about that and I understand this aspect [you understand where the $2n$ comes from] because of this & that ["since there are only 2 variables on the R.H.S (...)"] but I don't understand this specific aspect [the $-1$ part.]). In short: while you made your problem clear, you didn't show any effort to explain what you understood and what you didn't.

Comment: @Auberon. I upvoted your comment (FWIW), but I must confess that it took me a while to check that the delimiters were properly nested: "...properly (e.g., [my note, the comma should be here] ... [...] ... [... (...)] ... [...])". Yup, this Dyck language sample is legitimate. [insert grinning emoticon here.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $n$ be the length of a string. We start with the (non-terminal) symbol $S$ which has length $n=1$.

Using $n - 1$ rules of form $(non-terminal) \rightarrow (non-terminal)(non-terminal)$ we can construct  a string containing $n$ non-terminal symbols.

Then on each non-terminal symbol of said string of length $n$ we apply a rule of form $(non-terminal) \rightarrow (terminal)$. i.e. we apply $n$ rules.

In total we will have applied $n - 1 + n = 2n - 1$ rules.

**example**

Observe following grammar in Chomsky-normal form.

$
\begin{align}
S & \to AB \\
A & \to BC | AC\\
A & \to h|b\\
B & \to a \\
C & \to z \\
\end{align}
$

Consider following derivation

$
\begin{align}
\text{Current string} & & \text{rule applied} & & \text{#rules applied} & & \text{#length of string} \\
S & & \text{\\} & & 0 & & 1 \\
AB & & S \to AB & & 1 & & 2 \\
BCB & & A \to BC & & 2 & & 3 \\
\vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots \\
A\cdots CB & & \text{[multiple rules]} & & n-1 & & n
\end{align}
$

This last line represents a string containing only non-terminals. You can see that a string containing $n$ non-terminals is derived using $n-1$ rules. Let's continue. Applying $n$ rules of form $A \to a$ to each non-terminal in the string above gives you a string containing only terminals and thus a string from the language decided by the grammar. The length of the string has not changed (it's still $n$) but we applied an additional $n$ rules so in total we have applied $n-1 + n = 2n - 1$ rules.

While this explanation hopefully gives you an intuitive understanding, I think it would be an useful excercise to construct a formal proof using [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).

Comment: :Could you tell why we use $n−1$ rules of the form $A \to BC$.

Comment: @justin Added an example to my answer.

Comment: :Could you tell how the length of string becomes 1 in the first step.

Comment: $S$ has length $1$,  it consists out of one symbol... What are you confused about

Comment: :Do you mean _S_ to be the start symbol?

Comment: Yes.  $S$ is usually used as the start symbol.

Comment: :Could you tell whether _S_ is a part of the rule $S \to AB$.If _S_ is a part shouldn't we say _S_ too is a rule?

Comment: @justin $S$ isn't a rule, it's a symbol... And you start every derivation with it. You take $S$ and **then** you apply your **first** rule of form $S /to AB$. So when you only have $S$, you haven't applied any rules yet.

Comment: The first part of the "proof" regarding changing to non-terminals is clear however the second part regarding changing the variables to terminals in n steps ,what if one of the variables has only a rule to another two variables and not a terminal?

Comment: @OmarHossamAhmed Then it means there is no string of length $n$ in the language generated by the grammar, or at least you've used the wrong non-terminal rules.

Answer (score 3):

And each of the $A \to B C$ produtions make the sentential form one longer. You start with length $1$, to reach $n$ means $n - 1$ steps. If a string has length $n$, there will be $n$ steps to get the terminals. In all, $2 n - 1$ steps.

Comment: :Do you mean to say that the _start_ symbol is of length 1?

Comment: @justin Yes, he does.

Answer (score 3):

Let us consider an simple example.

```
A -> BC
B -> b
C -> c
```

String to be generated is `bc`.

Then the steps are.

```
A -> BC
  -> bC
  -> bc
```

Thus no of steps required is 3.
That is $2n-1$.